# Translate mssql script to mysql update column in table with latest date in other table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Hello I have one table with contracts and another table with all the changes that has been made to these contracts.
I now need to update all of my contracts with a column modifieddate. This should be the latest change on the contract.
In the table with changes there are dates so I need to get the latest existing date there for each contract.
I have managed to do a script in mssql but I dont get it right in mysql.
Maybe someone can help me.

Mssql

```
update Contract SET
    Contract.ModifiedBySystemUserId =
        (select top 1 eh2.SystemUserId FROM EntityHistory eh2  WHERE eh2.EntityId = eh.EntityId
        and eh2.EntityType = 5 ORDER BY eh2.EventDate DESC)
from 
    Contract c
    INNER JOIN EntityHistory eh on eh.EntityType = 5 and c.contractId = eh.EntityId
```

Comment: TOP isn't MySQL, so that's the bit you have to change. If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please tag your DBMS correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below query:

```
 update Contract c
  INNER JOIN EntityHistory eh on eh.EntityType = 5 and c.contractId = eh.EntityId
  SET Contract.ModifiedBySystemUserId = (select eh2.SystemUserId 
                                        FROM EntityHistory eh2  
                                        WHERE eh2.EntityId = eh.EntityId and eh2.EntityType = 5 
                                        ORDER BY eh2.EventDate DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks so simple now but I could not get it right :)